# CSV to nested JSON Python

Tags: python, json, csv

I have a csv file which only has one column consisting of 200 rows. I want to use each row count as "priority" and each row value as "name", obtaining the following json format:

```
[{ "model" : "mymodel",
   "pk" : ROW_ID,
   "fields":{
      "name" : ROW_VALUE,
      "priority" : ROW_ID
},
{ "model" : "mymodel",
   "pk" : ROW_ID,
   "fields":{
      "name" : ROW_VALUE,
      "priority" : ROW_ID
}]
```

I know that I have to use `csv` and `json`, but quite confused about the nested json format. Any help on this?

Comment: In what sense is your file `csv` if it only has one column. Is it just a list of 200 values separated by line breaks?

Comment: It looks like this : https://imgur.com/GaZdgk4 @MarkMeyer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to open the file and loop through the lines. You can use `enumerate()` to get the value of the line number (starting at zero). Build an array of dictionaries and the pass it to `json.dumps` to make a JSON string:

```
import json

with open(filePath) as f:
    next(f) #skip the header
    l = []
    for line, value in enumerate(f):
        l.append({
            "model" : "mymodel",
            "pk": line,
            "fields": {
                "name": value.strip(),
                "priority": line
            }
        })
print(json.dumps(l))
# or for indented output like below:
# json.dumps(l, indent=2)
```

This will print:

```
[
  {
    "model": "mymodel",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
      "name": "Afghanistan",
      "priority": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "model": "mymodel",
    "pk": 2,
    "fields": {
      "name": "Albania",
      "priority": 1
    }
  },
  ...
]
```

Comment: Added `print(json.dumps(l,indent=4))

with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(l, outfile, indent= 4)` for prettifying the json and open it in a file.